# worst-case time complexity of str.find in python

Tags: python, c, string, algorithm, time-complexity

The question is already in the title, what is the worst-case time complexity of the C implementation of `str.find(string, substring)` in Python if *n* is the length of `string` and *m* is the length of `substring`? The source code (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99f5a0475ead/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) seems to talk about the boyer-moore-horspool algorithm, which according to Wikipedia has a worst-case complexity of O(*m***n*).

***EDIT:*** O(*m***n*) refers to the runnning time of the boyer-moore-horspool Algorithm, which finds ***all*** the occurrences of a substring in a string. Python's `str.find` Method finds only ***one*** occurrence of the substring, so it's (`str.find`) will depend on the position of the first occurrence of `substring`. So *NO*, I haven't already posted the answer.

Comment: They also provide a link *for some more background* http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Comment: what is your actual question, you already have the answer in the documentation you linked to?

Comment: If you have  a lot of repeated substrings then looking for a single substring is still going to be O(m*n). The link states under constraints *no worse than the current algorithm in worst case (O(nm))* and *many real-life searches should be good, very few should be worst case* which makes it pretty obvious that there are possible cases  where it will be O(nm). The cases where it is always linear or sublinear involve building tables where the cost of building would outweigh the complexity unless the string was very long.

Comment: Also under constraints is small setup overhead; no dynamic allocation in the fast path (O(m) for speed, O(1) for storage) so there is obviously not a lot stored. Python can use better algorithms based on the condition of the string but for the naive approach it is worst case O(m*n) – You might find this an interesting read http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2010/12/06/efficient-substring-searching/

Answer (score 3):

> The [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99f5a0475ead/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) seems to talk about the boyer-moore-horspool algorithm, which according to Wikipedia has a worst-case complexity of O(m*n).

Your answer is `O(m*n)` for CPython. In general, it's obviously implementation-dependent.

**EDIT:** Yes, I wondered why you're asking this, if you already had made the research.

Comment: I'm not so sure since the Wikipedia entry of the Boyer-Moore Algorithm says that there is an optimization ("Galil Rule") which produces linear time in the worst-case