# finding the time complexity of the program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How do we find the time complexity of below program? For the below program should the time complexity be `O(N)` or `O(N*M)` or `O(N*M*M)`?

Take-1: `O(N)`

- to scan N elements in the input array

Take-2: `O(N*M)`

- N is number of elements in the input array
- M is length of the longest email address in the list for `split` and `find`

Take-3: `O(N*M*M)`

- N is number of elements in the input array
- first M is length of the longest email address until @ in the list for `split`
- second M is length of the longest email address in the list for  `find`

```
input_mails = ["abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com"] 
for email in input_mails: 
    first_part, second_part = email.split("@") 
    position = email.find(".")
    print(first_part)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of the given program will be `N*2M` ~ `O(N * M)` where:

```
N: number of elements in the input array (input_mails)
M: length of the longest email address in the list
```

***Here's how the operations contribute to the time complexity:***

1. Looping through `N` elements in the input array: `O(N)`
2. Splitting each email address at `@`: `O(M)`, as splitting depends on the length of the longest email address.
3. Finding the position of `.`: `O(M)`, as finding the dot also depends on the length of the longest email address. Now, one point to note here is `find()` has the worst case time complexity of `O(p*q)` where `p` being the length of the longer string, `q`, the shorter string you search for. But since you mentioned you need to find dot(`.`) so `q` becomes 1 and for the context of your code it becomes `O(M)`.

---

##### References and further reading:

1. [Worst case time complexity of `str.find()` in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728969/worst-case-time-complexity-of-str-find-in-python)
2. [Further reading around `str.find()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220418/runtime-of-pythons-if-substring-in-string)
3. [Splitting and joining a string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-split-join-string/)

Comment: one of my reference mentioned that the time complexity of the program is O(n), where n is the number of email addresses in the input list. This is because the program uses a loop to iterate through each email address in the list and performs constant time operations within the loop. The split() and find() functions used in the program are considered constant time operations. Quite confused, please confirm if this is `O(N)` or `O(N*M)`?

Comment: @Matthew Please refer to the links which I attached for reading about the time complexity of `find()` and `split()`. You will get to know their internal workings. By logic also find() cannot be a constant operation `O(1)`. Best we get in `find()` across programming language is `O(log n)` when string or array is sorted and we apply binary search but here the string is not guaranteed to be sorted. so worst case is `linear search` which is `O(m)`.

Comment: @Matthew Also, since we're using the `find()` of python so you will notice in the link I attached it uses [Boyer-Moore-horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20Boyer,Horspool%20in%201980%20as%20SBM.&text=It%20is%20a%20simplification%20of,Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt%20algorithm.) which gives average as `O(p)` but worst case is O(p*q) and I have mentioned what `p` and `q` are in my post. Hope it clarifies your doubt.